# Accessing SSRS in local network without a domain

Tags: reporting-services

I just wanna know if this is possible, as I have set up a simple SSRS in our home and I can't access it using other PC in the same network, I have read that I need a domain but that is only possible if I am using Windows server, but I only have  the client version.

Is there any possible way that I can work this out in the client version of windows? so that I don't need to install windows server

Comment: So what happens when you try to access it now? Does it work on the local machine and do you have network connectivity to say, a static web page? You might be able to use NTLM which does not require a domain server.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, I can access  the SSRS in local machine, and yes to all of that, I am currently using RSWindowsNegotiate, I have tried using NTLM but SSRS begins to ask for login credentials

Comment: You're unlikely to get single sign on working without a domain because the server doesn't know who you are. Does this help? Your question might be a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348649/how-to-authenticate-ssrs-externally-using-automatic-ntlm-credential-passing

Comment: Nah I guess you've already done what was mentioned in that link